# Select e div dinamico

Tags: php, jquery

Eu queria fazer uma sequência de `select` dinâmicos, por exemplo:

```
1º - Seleciona a Categoria (Veiculos);
2º - Seleciona a SubCategoria (Carros);
3º - Seleciona a Marca (do carro);
4º - Seleciona o Modelo (da marca);
5º - Seleciona o Ano (do modelo);
```

Tudo isso vem de um banco de dados, segue um exemplo do meu 1º `select`:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Categoria:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
         <select name="categorias" id="categorias" class="form-control">
             <option value="0">Escolha uma Categoria</option>
             <?php
                 foreach ($categorias as $categoria) :
                 if($categoria['id_categoria_pai'] == 0){
                    echo "<option value='".$categoria['id']."'>".$categoria['nome']."</option>";
                 }
                 endforeach;
             ?>
         </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

O próximo `select` fica escondido em uma `div`. Exemplo:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="marcaCarros" id="Carro">
         <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Marca:</label>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
             <select name="marcaCarros" id="marcaCarros"  class="form-control">
             </select>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

O código Javascript que estou usando:

```
$('.marcaCarros').hide();

$('#subcategorias').on('change', function() {
  var selecionado = $(this).val();

  $('.marcaCarros').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == selecionado) {
      $(this).toggle();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Como eu posso fazer pra passar os IDS para as `div` e popular os `select` de forma dinâmica?
Se o usuário mudar o primeiro `select` por exemplo para imóveis, ele tem que alterar automaticamente, ou alterar o 2º pra ao invés de carros, para motos, mude automaticamente.

Mais uma coisa, nesse exemplo do carro, vão ter características também, que também estão em uma `div` e aqui eu também queria fazer de forma dinâmica:

```
<div id="Carro" class="div-sel">              
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Características</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox" name="caracteristicas[]" value="air-bag"> Air-Bag </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox" name="caracteristicas[]" value="air-bag-duplo"> Air-Bag Duplo </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox" name="caracteristicas[]" value="alarme"> Alarme </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox" name="caracteristicas[]" value="ar-quente"> Ar-quente </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox" name="caracteristicas[]" value="ac"> Ar-condicionado </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox" name="caracteristicas[]" value="ac-digital"> Ar-condicionado-digital </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Não sei se eu consegui me explicar, mas estou começando agora e quebrando a cabeça.

Comment: Existem várias perguntas no StackOverflow relacionadas ao uso de Ajax para atualizar dinamicamente um `select`.

Answer (score 1):

Crie um arquivo php e salve como veiculos.php

```
$tipo = $_GET['tipo'];

//Conexão
//Conecta ao banco de dados
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "dev") or print (mysql_error()); 

//Seleciona o banco de dados
$db = mysql_select_db("veiculos", $con) or print(mysql_error()); 

if($tipo == 'marcas') {

    //Lista marcas*************************************
    //Faz a consulta
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marcas", $con);


    $marcas = array();

    //Lista os resultados em $marcas
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $marcas[] = $row;
        }
    }

    //Escreve o json
    echo json_encode($marcas);

} else {

    $idmarca = $_GET['id'];

    //Lista modelos*************************************
    //Faz a consulta
    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM modelos WHERE marca_id = ".$idmarca, $con);

    $modelos = array();


    //Lista os resultados em $marcas
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $modelos[] = $row;
        }
    }

    //Escreve o json
    echo json_encode($modelos);
}

//Fecha a conexão
mysql_close($con); 


?>
```

E substitua o script por

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $.get('veiculos.php?tipo=marcas', function(marcas) {
        //Preenche select marcas
        $(marcas).each(function() {
            option = '<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.marca + '</option>';
            $('#marcas').append(option);
        });
    }, 'json');

    //Preenche o select modelos com
    //os modelos da marca escolhida
    $('#marcas').change(function() {

        var id = $('#marcas').val();

        $.get('veiculos.php?tipo=modelos&id=' + id, function(modelos) {
            //Preenche select marcas
            $('#modelos').empty();
            $('#modelos').append('<option value="">-- Escolha um modelo --</option>');

            var idMarca = $('#marcas').val();

            $(modelos).each(function() {
                option = '<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.modelo + '</option>';
                $('#modelos').append(option);
            });

        }, 'json');

    });
});
```

E use o seguinte SQL para gerar os dados no seu banco de dados

```
    -- Copiando estrutura do banco de dados para veiculos
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `veiculos` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci */;
    USE `veiculos`;


    -- Copiando estrutura para tabela veiculos.marcas
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `marcas` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `marca` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    -- Copiando dados para a tabela veiculos.marcas: ~2 rows (aproximadamente)
    DELETE FROM `marcas`;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `marcas` DISABLE KEYS */;
    INSERT INTO `marcas` (`id`, `marca`) VALUES
        (1, 'Fiat'),
        (2, 'Volkswagen');
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `marcas` ENABLE KEYS */;


    -- Copiando estrutura para tabela veiculos.modelos
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `modelos` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `modelo` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `marca_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    -- Copiando dados para a tabela veiculos.modelos: ~0 rows (aproximadamente)
    DELETE FROM `modelos`;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `modelos` DISABLE KEYS */;
    INSERT INTO `modelos` (`id`, `modelo`, `marca_id`) VALUES
        (1, 'Pálio', 1),
        (2, 'Punto', 1),
        (3, 'Siena', 1),
        (4, 'Uno', 1),
        (5, 'Gol', 2),
        (6, 'Saveiro', 2),
        (7, 'Fox', 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Select dinâmico

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var option = null;

$(document).ready(function() {


    $.get('veiculos.php?tipo=marcas', function(marcas) {
        //Preenche select marcas
        $(marcas).each(function() {
            option = '<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.marca + '</option>';
            $('#marcas').append(option);
        });
    }, 'json');

    //Preenche o select modelos com
    //os modelos da marca escolhida
    $('#marcas').change(function() {

        var id = $('#marcas').val();

        $.get('veiculos.php?tipo=modelos&id=' + id, function(modelos) {
            //Preenche select marcas
            $('#modelos').empty();
            $('#modelos').append('<option value="">-- Escolha um modelo --</option>');

            var idMarca = $('#marcas').val();

            $(modelos).each(function() {
                option = '<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.modelo + '</option>';
                $('#modelos').append(option);
            });

        }, 'json');

    });
});

</script>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Marcas:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select name="marcas" id="marcas" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">-- Escolha uma marca --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Modelo:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select name="modelos" id="modelos" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">-- Escolha um modelo --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Coloque tudo na mesma resposta, você está criando 2 respostas.